# NFS (EFS) close-to-open consistency rule not respected?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, nfs, distributed-system, amazon-efs

I have a simple setup in AWS where 2 VMs (EC2) mount a common Elastic File System (EFS). EFS is backed by NFSv4, which offers close-to-open (CTO) consistency, meaning that (quoting azure [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-netapp-files/performance-linux-mount-options#close-to-open-consistency)): "no matter the state of the (efs client) cache, on open the most recent data for a file is always presented to the application.". In this context, "most recent data" means that a write operation was concluded by a successful call to *close()* (see section 8 of [About the NFS protocol](https://nfs.sourceforge.net/)).

In my case, VM A compiles a project and VM B checks for a resulting library file. According to the CTO rule, VM B should definitely see the file after compilation, but I do not observe this - it takes several tens of seconds until the file becomes visible to it.

Interestingly, if I disable NFS client caches on VM B, the file is visible right away - this suggests that NFS client caches are not in fact invalidated on *open()*.

I already made a detailed [post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUZJvmtA6ESQ6bkxP6ur6Pbw/strange-file-consistency-issue-with-efs) on the AWS repost forum with complete steps to reproduce the issue.

Has anyone encountered something similar with NFS based distributed storage? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out as I believe it is the same phenomenon described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311710/nfs-cache-cleaning-command?rq=2), namely CTO doesn't apply if the file isn't already seen by the NFS client.

As explained in the "Directory entry caching" section of the [man](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs) page, the NFS client caches directory entry lookups - so what can happen is the following:

- file is looked up at time t=0, it's not yet there and this result is cached
- file is created by another client at t=1
- file is queried again at t=2 by the first instance but the caches are not yet expired, so a "No such file or directory" error appears.

The way I understand it now is that CTO is actually simply more general - it works on the directory level as well. So before opening a file, one must also first open the directory to see the latest entries.